# Generating function of $1 + x^k + x^{2k} +\cdots$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I know that the generating function of $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$ is 
$\frac{1}{1 - x}$.
But what is the generating function of $1 + x^k + x^{2k} + x^{3k} + \cdots$ ?

Comment: This is just $1 + (x^k) + (x^k)^2 + (x^k)^3 + ... = (1 - x^k)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $$\frac{1}{1-x} =1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\ldots, \tag{$|x|<1$}$$
then $$\frac{1}{1-x^k} =1+(x^k)+(x^k)^2+(x^k)^3+(x^k)^4+\ldots \tag{$|x^k|<1$}$$
Note that $|x|<1$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ implies $|x^k|<1$.

Comment: Don't you have to specify a certain set of values for $x$ for this to be true? For example, when $x=2$, the RHS diverges.

Comment: @ProtectedSource You can consider the generating function as a formal power series, then $x$ is just an unevaluated letter and no convergence is needed.